# Jenkins email-ext Pre-send groovy script is resuting in attachement

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I entered this simple line in Pre-Send Script:

```
msg.setContent("Hi there!" , "html/text");
```

When I receive the email, the body is empty and there is a file attached which contains Hi there!.

What do I need to do for this to come out in the body of the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written a wrong mime-type. The following should work:

```java
msg.setContent("Hi there!" , "text/html"); // not "̶h̶t̶m̶l̶/̶t̶e̶x̶t̶"̶
```

A complete list of available mime-types can be found [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html).